# Migration of MQ messages to a new consumer on a different server

Tags: ibm-mq

We are migrating some queues to allow a new consumer to read the messages
We have the following setup in a cluster
2 Full repos QMF1 and QMF2 with a Queue Alias (QAF)
2 Partial repos QMB1 and QMB2 with a Cluster Queue Local (QLB)

Message from APP1 put messages to the QAF queues with a target of QLB, application APP2 consumes the messages from QLB.

Routes then are

```
APP1 -> QAF (QMF1) -> QLB (QMB1) -> APP2
APP1 -> QAF (QMF1) -> QLB (QMB2) -> APP2
APP1 -> QAF (QMF2) -> QLB (QMB1) -> APP2
APP1 -> QAF (QMF2) -> QLB (QMB2) -> APP2
```

In order to achieve the migration without changing the Applications configuration we have introduced a new Partial QMGR QMN1 and additional Cluster Queue Alias QAN with a non-Clustered QLB, this allows the QAF TARGET to be changed from QLB to QAN

Routes ideally is

```
APP1 -> QAF (QMF1)  -> QAN (QMN1) -> QLB (QMN1) -> APP3
```

Initial low volume test can see this is working OK, however when looking at the queues available to QMN1 we have the following
QMGR QMN1 has

```
QLB on QMN1, Local queue
QLB on QMB1, cluster queue 
QLB on QMB2, cluster queue
```

Is this now going to be an issue when volume of traffic is introduced, will it be possible for the below scenarios to also work

```
APP1 -> QAN (QMN1) -> QLB (QMB1) -> APP2
APP1 -> QAN (QMN1) -> QLB (QMB2) -> APP2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opening a queue, a matching local, non-clustered queue is selected ahead of any clustered queues.

In the configuration described, this means that messages sent to QMN1 with a target queue name of QLB will be put to the local queue instance and the clustered queues will not be considered.

Reference:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=call-name-resolution

Comment: Thanks, so it is working as designed i was only dubious if the local queue became unavailable for any reason (full or corrupt queue).   Although i have actually had another look at the set up and have also decided to remove the Cluster from the queues on QMB1 and QMB2 and these are no longer available